# Android Query: Wrong Umlauts (HTML download)

Tags: android, aquery

i use android query to download the html from my site.

```
aq.ajax(url, String.class, new AjaxCallback<String>() {

        @Override
        public void callback(String url, String html, AjaxStatus status) {
            wvTest.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
        }

    });
```

My site contains umlauts (ä, ü, ö) and they are displayed wrong (black squares with a question mark). the wrong umlauts are in the html string from android query.

how can i fix this so that he loads the right umlauts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that the file that you are loading is in the same charset encoding like you have specified in your request ("utf-8") ...